# How to merge x-axis data from two ranges?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Consider the data below:

```
1-Jan-2010  3   2-Feb-2009  9
5-Apr-2010  4   18-Apr-2010 5
10-Sep-2012 9   1-Oct-2011  8
```

The first two columns are for individual `A`, the last two for individual `B`.

**Is it possible to create a graph such that both ranges are displayed under a common x axis?** In other words, 6 data points 9noted with two different symbols with the corresponding date for each data point?

This would be equivalent to a merge of two distinct graphs, to a common x-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this roughly what you want?:

[image: WA108868 example]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks. I did not think about meeting the data this way.

Comment: @pnuts Hello! sorry for asking here in the comment. I asked a question here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/164533/google-spreadsheets-charts-drawing-continuous-chart-based-on-multiple-data-rang?noredirect=1#comment150900_164533, and someone suggested your answer. Unfortunately, it's not helpful in my case. Could you please take a look at my question and check if you can help. Thanks in advance.