# Google Spreadsheets Charts: Drawing continuous chart based on multiple data ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a big set of data that I split it into 2 ranges (here I am just showing small data for clarification). 
I want to draw one chart based on those 2 ranges, to get a result as the "**Desired Result**" chart.
However, what I am getting now is the "**Current Result**" chart.
The data range I am using as shown is: `A3:A8,B3:B8,C3:C8,D3:D8,E3:E8,F3:F8`

My question is: Is it possible to draw one graph continuously based to ranges in different columns? 
If that is possible, how can we achieve it?

[image]

**EDIT**
The question [How to merge x-axis data from two ranges?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108868/how-to-merge-x-axis-data-from-two-ranges) does not fit my case. In there, the values of `Y` axis are all in the same column `A`, and the values of `X` axis are in two different columns `B` and `C`. 
In my case, the values of `Y` axis **AND** `X` axis are in 2 different columns. `B` & `E` for axis `X`, `C` & `F` for axis `Y`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge x-axis data from two ranges?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108868/how-to-merge-x-axis-data-from-two-ranges)

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you for the comment, but that does not answer my question. In my case, I have the columns arranged exactly as showed in the cells `A3:F8`, and I want to draw the graph based on columns in the way they are arranged in.

Comment: @Tedinoz I updated my question to describe the difference from the question you suggested.

Comment: You are wrong about "merge x-axis from two ranges". This **is** the approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to create data in two columns for the x-axis as outlined in [How to merge x-axis data from two ranges?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/108871/196152)

---

**Data and chart**

[image: Snapshot]

---

**Basic Chart details**

[image: chart details]